# WPF - GridView OnEditEnded event

Tags: c#, wpf, events, gridview

I use Entity Framework 7 and gridview for see and edit data in gridview. After editing cell I need to save new value, but CellEditEnding event invoked before changing source data (ItemsSource property) and database dosen't update.

Event listener code:

```
private void DataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.EditAction == System.Windows.Controls.DataGridEditAction.Commit)
            {
                App.DBContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Advance thanks!

Comment: Why would your View have the responsibility of saving changes to the DB ? When that asked, here all the events of data-grid: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid?view=windowsdesktop-7.0.. the one you ask for does not exist... Most likely for good reasons

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @NawedNabiZada Because I work on outsource project (which will be used at most once) with ultra low budget and very tight deadlines.
I tried to make "my" Dbset (inherited from Dbset<T>), but I don't understand how make realization of Entity Type (i searched, but find anything) and I decided to abandon this idea.

(Sorry for my english)